# Is void** portable C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, generics

I want to implement a generic growing array and use this struct for it:

```
struct dynamic_array
{
    void** data;
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
};
```

Because `void*` doesn't allow arithmetic, I wanted to know if a `void*` array allows it, since it is a *pointer* to a `void*`. If that doesn't work, I'd like to know how else I could implement a generic array.

Edit: Since not everyone knows what I want to do with it, here's a code snippet how I could use the array:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < array->length; i++)
{
    if(strcmp((char*)array->data[i], some_string) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course it's not only going to be char* but struct* too, and I know I have to cast them, but void* should allow casting back and forth without data loss, right?

Comment: Even though `void *` doesn't allow arithmetic, `void **` (which is a completely different type) does.

Comment: `void *` doesn't allow arithmetic because the compiler doesn't know what it's pointing to. `void **` does, because we know exactly what it points to: pointers.

Comment: While `void **` will allow you to do pointer arithmetic, I have to wonder if that's really what you want.  If you want a generic dynamic array, I think you want to use `void *` and then type-cast it.

Comment: Note: as `array->data[i]` is a `void *`, the cast in `if(strcmp((char*)array->data[i], some_string) == 0)` is not needed.

Comment: `strcmp((char*)array->data[i], ...` no need to cast here (in C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works. A pointer to void (`void *`) is a perfectly valid data object, so you can have an array of pointers to void, and access elements in that array in the normal way.

An example code snippet:

```
int i;
char c;
float f;

struct dynamic_array a;
a.capacity = 1024;
a.data = malloc(a.capacity * sizeof(void*));
a.data[0] = &i;
a.data[1] = &c;
a.data[2] = &f;
a.length = 3;
```

As Lee Daniel Crocker wrote, `void *` doesn't allow pointer arithmetic because the compiler doesn't know what it's pointing to. But `void **` does, because we know exactly what it points to: pointers.

Comment: Minor: On code review, `a.data = malloc(a.capacity * sizeof(void*));` has the usual "was the correct type used?" concern.  This requires a look-up of the details of `struct dynamic_array` which may exist in another file (maybe dynamic_array.h). OTOH, if code was `a.data = malloc(a.capacity * sizeof *(a.data));`, the right size is certain without a  type check.  Further, this code idiom is easier to maintain.